# What is the equivalent of .NET Framework ModelMetadataProvider in .Net Core?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

for get property `DisplayName` attribute value, `ModelMetadataProvider` used at .NET Framework versions.

```
ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForProperty(null, ClassType, PropertyName).DisplayName;
```

and I tried get `DisplayName` in .NET 6:

```
class SampleClass{
   [Display(Name = "FirstName", ResourceType = typeof(MyResource))]
   public string Name{ get; set; }
}

Type ClassType = typeof(SampleClass);
string PropertyName = "Name";
string displayName = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(ClassType)
                            .Cast<PropertyDescriptor>()
                            .ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.DisplayName)
                            .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Key == PropertyName).ToString();
```

The `DisplayName` value will be received, but the output value does not change when the CultureInfo is changed!

Comment: `ModelMetadataProvider` is specific to ASP.NET, but is [available in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.modelmetadataprovider). The way the class is instantiated is different since ASP.NET Core moves away from static fields towards dependency injection, but the functionality is the same.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, This is used in a static class and I prefer not to use dependency injection.I got what you are saying.

Comment: You are of course free to explicitly instantiate a `DefaultModelMetadataProvider` somewhere, but that apparently also requires a `ICompositeMetadataDetailsProvider`, so it can get a little involved. (I have no experience using these types.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using the following code, *DisplayName* value (which has a resource) can be accessed without using *ModelMetadataProvider* and dependency injection, and it also works by changing the language.

```
class SampleClass{
   [Display(Name = "FirstName", ResourceType = typeof(MyResource))]
   public string Name{ get; set; }
}

Type ClassType = typeof(SampleClass);
string PropertyName = "Name";
string displayName = "";

MemberInfo property = ModelType.GetProperty(Property);
displayName = property.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>()?.GetName();
```